# C# client-server vs multiclient-server c#

Tags: c#, networking, server, client

Can anyone explain to me the difference between a single client-server and a multiclient server in c#?

Like if i want to make a chatroom with many clients at the same time, i am not sure i understand correctly but do we just assign new IPs for each client and the server reads them?

Here's the client code

```
        public Form1()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();
        read=new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunClient));
        read.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.Resources.ResourceManager resources = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        //this.axSkin1 = new AxACTIVESKINLib.AxSkin();
        this.tmsg = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.bsend = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.tchat = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.Message = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.Box1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        //((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axSkin1)).BeginInit();
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // axSkin1
        // 
        //this.axSkin1.Enabled = true;
        //this.axSkin1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(368, 272);
        //this.axSkin1.Name = "axSkin1";
        //this.axSkin1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axSkin1.OcxState")));
        //this.axSkin1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 32);
        //this.axSkin1.TabIndex = 0;
        //// 
        // tmsg
        // 
        this.tmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Coral;
        this.tmsg.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(32, 268);
        this.tmsg.Name = "tmsg";
        this.tmsg.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(336, 20);
        this.tmsg.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tmsg.Text = "";
        this.tmsg.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.tmsg_KeyPress);
        // 
        // bsend
        // 
        this.bsend.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.bsend.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
        this.bsend.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(168, 311);
        this.bsend.Name = "bsend";
        this.bsend.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 24);
        this.bsend.TabIndex = 3;
        this.bsend.Text = "&send";
        this.bsend.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bsend_Click);
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.tchat);
        this.groupBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(178)));
        this.groupBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 56);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(352, 176);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "Message Exchange";
        // 
        // tchat
        // 
        this.tchat.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(178)));
        this.tchat.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 24);
        this.tchat.Name = "tchat";
        this.tchat.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedVertical;
        this.tchat.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 136);
        this.tchat.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tchat.Text = "";
        // 
        // Message
        // 
        this.Message.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(178)));
        this.Message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.Message.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 244);
        this.Message.Name = "Message";
        this.Message.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(352, 56);
        this.Message.TabIndex = 5;
        this.Message.TabStop = false;
        this.Message.Text = "Message";
        // 
        // Box1
        // 
        this.Box1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(299, 3);
        this.Box1.Name = "Box1";
        this.Box1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 51);
        this.Box1.TabIndex = 6;
        this.Box1.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 342);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Box1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.bsend);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tmsg);
        //this.Controls.Add(this.axSkin1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Message);
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(432, 408);
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(408, 376);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(408, 376);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Client";
        this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        //((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axSkin1)).EndInit();
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //axSkin1.ApplySkin((int)Handle);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    public void RunClient()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Icon=new Icon("1.ico");
            this.Box1.Image=Image.FromFile("1.gif");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        try
        {
            tchat.Text="trying to connect to the server";
            // Step 1: create TcpClient and connect to server
            client=new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("LocalHost",20000);
            // Step 2: get NetworkStream associated with TcpClient
            stream=client.GetStream();
            // create objects for writing and reading across stream
            reader=new BinaryReader(stream);
            writer=new BinaryWriter(stream);
            //send welcome to server
            writer.Write("Welcome server");
            tchat.Text+="\r\n Client :Welcome server";
            string reply;
            while(true)
            {
                //step 3: read message from server
                try
                {
                    reply=reader.ReadString();
                    int len=tchat.Text.Length;
                    tchat.AppendText("\r\nServer :"+reply);
                    tchat.Select(len,10+reply.Length);
                    tchat.SelectionColor=Color.Red;
                    tchat.ScrollToCaret();
                }
                //handle execption if the server terminate
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    //step 5:close connection
                    MessageBox.Show("Can not find server..!");
                    reader.Close();
                    writer.Close();
                    stream.Close();
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this,"Error while connecting to server",
                this.Text,MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }

    }
    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
    }

    private void tmsg_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar=='\r'&&client!=null)
        {

            writer.Write(tmsg.Text);
            int len=tchat.TextLength;
            tchat.AppendText("\r\nClient  :"+tmsg.Text);
            tchat.Select(len,10+tmsg.TextLength);
            tchat.SelectionColor=Color.Blue;
            tmsg.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void bsend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(client!=null)
        {
            writer.Write(tmsg.Text);
            int len=tchat.TextLength;
            tchat.AppendText("\r\nClient  :"+tmsg.Text);
            tchat.Select(len,10+tmsg.TextLength);
            tchat.SelectionColor=Color.Blue;
            tmsg.Clear();
        }

    }
}
```

I could post server code too if needed, the lecturer said he'll appreciate the attempt at least.

Okay so i can't format it so here's the server code https://pastebin.com/bzhr20Qk

Comment: You seem to have only provided client code, yet you're asking about the server...

Comment: Just added a link to the server code

Comment: oh that server code is *horrible*; that does the worst of both worlds - it handles everything on one thread and is purely synchronous, so it will support multiple *sequential* clients, and multiple messages per client; but not multiple *concurrent* clients; if that is your lecturer's code, then... well I *guess* they could be *leading into* a complex area, but... yeah, that's bad code

Comment: Any ideas on how to get it to support multi concurrent clients?

Comment: Sure: see my answer

Answer (score 0):

*Fundamentally* there's no difference; the nature of a server application is:

- have a *listener* that listens for one or more connect attempts
- when a connect attempt is detected, initialize *some kind of code* to handle that connection, and then *presumably* go back to listening for connect attempts

what gets *interesting* is: how do you handle that connection? If you only expect one client, you can do everything in one thread:

- wait for a connection
- wait for a complete incoming message

  - process incoming message
  - (repeat)

if you expect a *low* number of connections, you can afford thread-per-connection:

- wait for a connection

  - start a thread for that connection
  - (repeat)

with (per connection)

- wait for a complete incoming message

  - process incoming message
  - (repeat)

However, for anything non-trivial, thread-per-connection simply doesn't work; you need to start thinking about asynchronous code and IO callbacks, and shared buffers, and all sorts of craziness. It is very hard to get right. Source: currently servicing 452,256 TCP/IP connections.

Re the specific question:

> but do we just assign new IPs for each client and the server reads them?

No, the client IP is the client IP is the client IP. The client connects to the listener port, and then at the server the listener hands over to an *established* TCP connection on an ephemeral port. You don't usually need to worry about this bit, it is handled automagically. But it is the *port number* that varies between *actual* connections.

Comment: So what i need to do is get the client to change port numbers each time a new connection happens?

I can't just change the code from scratch i have to edit it

Comment: @00qq00 "So what i need to do is get the client to change port numbers each time a new connection happens?" - absolutely nothing; that all happens behind the scenes when you accept the connection; look at the `LocalEndPoint` on the socket to see what I mean